# JS error: why can't the system find my js file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making my final project for university and I need to build a game for 2 players. whenever I load in the script with  the page can't seem to find the js. I've tried to put the script in other folders and it just seems to cannot find the script.

I placed the script in other folders, including the same folder where the current php file is. (head.php) and this did not work. If I paste the whole script file in the php file suddenly the js code does work.

This is the code from the main file welcome.php:

```
<script src="../scripts/validate_form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[image: the file sortation]

For debugging I put the file also in the tpl folder but that did not work either.

It cannot find any scripts what so ever.

Comment: Just use "/scripts/main.js" ? The forward slash at the beginning puts the request back at root

Comment: @zanderwar that doesn't work aswell

Comment: It most definitely should have unless you have done something strange, do you see it when you go to http://localhost/scripts/main.js ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ../ is getting it back to the root.

use:

```
<script src="/webpro/scripts/validate_form.js"></script>
```

This should fix the problem